# Would learning both XAML UI and XML UI be helpful in improving understanding of XML in general?

Tags: xml, xaml, xamarin

I'm familiar with `HTML/CSS`, and some non-UI programming using `C#`/`node.js`/`Java` and looking at options for building a simple mobile app.

I will definitely use Xamarin, and have to choose between Xamarin native and Xamarin Forms.

How much of an overlap is there between a UI coded in XAML and an Android UI coded in XML? I'm quite new to XML and am using it in `WCF`, `WPF` and now this mobile app.

To me its seems that they look pretty similar - in that either an `XAML` or an `XML` interface will force me to take a closer look at how `XML` works. Is that correct?

My goal with this simple app is to:

1. Become more familiar with XML in general
2. Become more familiar with XML UI coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little bit confused with this question, but I will try to answer.

### XML

XML (in general) has seven main commandments:

1. there are **namespaces**, **tags**, **attributes** and **text nodes**

   - actually, real hierarchy is richer, there are *declarations*, *comments*, *CDATA* and *other elements*, it is enough to read [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) to know them all.
2. there is only **one root**

   Probably, it is a reference to Bible.

   > Actually, **NO**
3. Every tag must be closed (self-closed are not violators: `<br />`)
4. Each tag has exactly one parent

   - as a consequence

     ```xml
     <root><a><b>illegal</a></b></root>
     ```

     is prohibited, because it is not clear, who is a parent for `<b>`
5. Every attribute **must** have a value enclosed in quotes. Good: `<a attr="" />`. Bad: `<button disabled />`
6. XML is **case-sensitive** (tag names, attr-names, ns-names, ...)
7. There are special symbols, like `<` `>` `&` — they **must** be escaped

   ```xml
   <my-namespace:text>&lt; MY TEXT IN ANGLE BRACKETS &gt;</my-namespace:text>
   ```

Knowing this rules, you could masterfully work with XML in 99% cases.

### XAML/Android UI XML ...

**XAML** and **Android UI XML** ­— are **XML-based** languages, this means, that both inherit syntax, punctuation, restrictions and other rules from XML, but the primary value of these languages — their specific tags (their semantics).

This means that you must know at least two languages (XAML and Android XML) to convert this Android XML:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

into this

```xml
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock>Hello, world!</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

Pure XML won't help you in solving of this task!

> Of course, these are two different UI :)

### Conclusion

- you could learn XAML, but XAML is **tags** — you will know a lot about XML, but not about Android UI XML.
- you could learn Android UI XML. The same thing: this knowledge is useless in XAML world
- you could learn XML-standards. Great. Now you could go to learn XAML, Android XML, XSLT, XSL or any other [XML-based language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_markup_languages), but pure XML - is just a foundation, a skeleton for other languages. May be for your own one;)